# AWS CLI error A client error (SignatureDoesNotMatch) occurred

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS CLI. The error

> A client error (SignatureDoesNotMatch) occurred when calling the
>   ListBuckets operation: The request signature we calculated does not
>   match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I tested the AWS CLI on my laptop and local server with the same credentials. There is no problem on my laptop. However, I get the error when I run on my local server.

What should I check?

Comment: You might check that the system clock on that instance is in sync, _e.g._ installing/running `ntpd`.  A sufficient clock skew will cause request signature calculations to not match.